Display relative date with `date` in human-readable format
I have date that I know will always be in future by at least one second.
Then I calculate difference between date now and target date in seconds.
But I can't figure out how to display second difference in human readable format with date.
I trying to convert second this way:
56 -> in 56 seconds
325 -> in 5 minutes 25 seconds
3613 -> in 1 hour 13 seconds
345603 -> in 4 days 3 seconds

I don't want to go beyond "days" value, and I don't want to display value if it's 0.
Is there a way to do that with date? Or should I do calculations myself in bash?

I have tried:
date --utc -d @"$seconds" +"%-dd %-Hh %-Mm %-Ss"

But there are two problems with this approach, first days value is incorrect, second this will display value even when it's 0

Modulo 60 => minutes. Modulo 3600 => hours. Modulo 86400 => days. Have fun! :-)

The word I was looking for was "duration".
Here solutions I found after I figured this out:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39452629/12038199
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69984084/12038199

Append below code block to one of the solutions above to solve this issue:
| sed 's/0[a-z] //g

or
| sed -E -e 's/0[a-z] //g' -e 's/ 0[a-z] ?//g'


#!/bin/bash
reldate() {
    local remains=$1
    set -- second s 60 minut es 60 hour s 24 day s 0
    local date=''
    while (($#)) ; do
        local unit=$1
        local plural=$2
        local n=$3
        shift 3

        local amount=$remains
        (( n )) && (( amount %= n ))
        if ((amount)) ; then
            (( amount > 1 )) && unit+=$plural
            date="$amount $unit $date"
            (( remains -= amount ))
        fi
        (( n )) && (( remains /= n ))
    done
    printf 'in %s' "${date% }"
}

set -eu

[[ $(reldate 56) == 'in 56 seconds' ]]
[[ $(reldate 325) == 'in 5 minutes 25 seconds' ]]
[[ $(reldate 3613) == 'in 1 hour 13 seconds' ]]
[[ $(reldate 345603) == 'in 4 days 3 seconds' ]]
[[ $(reldate 349203) == 'in 4 days 1 hour 3 seconds' ]]
[[ $(reldate 63072000) == 'in 730 days' ]]
[[ $(reldate 63071999) == 'in 729 days 23 hours 59 minutes 59 seconds' ]]


I'm not sure exactly but I think set broke something and after set -eu nothing getting printed like script exited.

@sloppy: If nothing gets printed and the exit code is 0, the function works correctly.

For fun, @choroba 's bash script rewritten in "simple to decipher" Python.
#!/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import sys

def relsecs(remains: int):
    dayz=''
    jobs=(['second','s',60],
          ['minut','es',60],
          ['hour','s',24],
          ['day','s',0])
    for unit,plural,n in jobs:
        amount=remains
        if n>0:
            amount%=n
        if amount>0:
            if amount>1:
                unit+=plural
            dayz=f'{amount} {unit} {dayz}'
            remains-=amount
        if n>0:
            remains//=n
    return dayz.strip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv)>1:
        print( relsecs( int( sys.argv[1] ) ) )
    else:
        print('use:',sys.argv[0].split('/')[-1],
              'seconds # print the time in days, hours, minutes and seconds.')

Test:
$ for secs in 56 325 3613 345603 349203 63072000 63071999; do z.py $secs ; done
56 seconds
5 minutes 25 seconds
1 hour 13 seconds
4 days 3 seconds
4 days 1 hour 3 seconds
730 days
729 days 23 hours 59 minutes 59 seconds

